# Looping and interrupting animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation

I'm hoping someone can tell me the correct way to go about looping an animation, interrupting the animation with another animation, and then resuming the original animation. The way I currently have my animation set up is like this:

```
-(void) firstAnimation
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f delay:0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction) animations:^{
        CGPoint bottomPoint = CGPointMake(215.0, 380.0);
        imgBee.center = bottomPoint;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}
```

And the interrupt:

```
-(void) interruptAnimation
{

    CGPoint point1 = CGPointMake(500, 500);
    CGPoint originalCenter = CGPointMake(215.0, 410.0);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f delay:0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse) animations:^{
        imgBee.center = point1;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        imgBee.center = originalCenter;
        [self firstAnimation];

    }];   
}
```

I'm pretty sure that's not the best way to go about this. When I interrupt with the `interruptAnimation` the original animation starts abruptly and when i call `[self firstAnimation]` the animation restarts abruptly also.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried passing `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` as well?

Comment: That seems to help somewhat with the abruptness of the transition, thanks. I've had to change the code around a bit though to get the effect i was after, removing the `AutoReverse` in place of adding another animation.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this Q&A about pausing and resuming animations, may this helps : [QA1673](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#qa/qa1673/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010053)